Outsourcing .properties file based on context path in Spring Boot application deployed on Tomcat
I want to deploy multiple Spring Boot applications in one Tomcat server, each with different context paths, and I want to outsource the properties of each application. Specifically, I want the properties file names to follow the pattern {app-context-path}.properties.
I tried to dynamically set the spring.config.name property based on the context path in SpringBootServletInitialiser classes configure method but it was failed because the application context wasn't initialized when configure method executed.
I'm wondering whether it is possible to outsource properties file based on the application context path or not?
Additional Information:

Spring Boot Version: 3.3.1
Tomcat Version: 10.1
Build Tool: Maven

Thank you for your suggestions and help!

Use an EnvironmentPostProcessor to do this.

@M.Deinum can you provide more details? I discovered that when the EnvironmentPostProcessor runs, the ServletContext has not yet been initialized.

What more details? What do you need the ServletContext for? You can check the passed in ApplicationContext if it is a WebApplicationContext you can obtain it from there.
